# creating image in jooma 1.5

Tags: joomla1.5, captcha

i am using the below code to create the image in joomla 1.5

```
            $session=JFactory::getSession();
    $randomnr = rand(1000, 9999);
    $session->set('randomr2',md5($randomnr));
    $im = imagecreatetruecolor(100, 38);

$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$grey = imagecolorallocate($im, 150, 150, 150);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);

imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 200, 35, $black);

//path to font - this is just an example you can use any font you like:

$font = dirName(__FILE__).'/font/karate/Karate.ttf';

imagettftext($im, 20, 4, 22, 30, $grey, $font, $randomnr);

imagettftext($im, 20, 4, 15, 32, $white, $font, $randomnr);

//prevent caching on client side:
header("Expires: Wed, 1 Jan 1997 00:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");

header ("Content-type: image/gif");
imagegif($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

but  it returns some strange characters when we run it in joomla 1.5
So is there any other way in joomla 1.5 to create a image from text.

Or i am looking for the plugin to create a captcha for my artform joomla 1.5 component.

Answer (score 0):

i have solved the issue myself to add `MIME ENCODING` for images,

just add two line

```
$document =& JFactory::getDocument();
$document->setMimeEncoding('image/png');
```

and you  will find your way.